# How can I join two tables don't have the same number of lines?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to program a something for a factory about production ...

The main thing is that I want to see how quantity is out of the stock for the raw matter but some times they bring back some of that matter if they finish.

So I created two view one for stock out it gave me 42 line and the second for stock in 14 line so in the third view I can put the values of the first view minus the second,
but it doesn't work because it always gives me 14 line instead of 42.

This is my first view of stock out:

```
CREATE VIEW V_MOUVEMENT_01(ARTID,plvqe,plvmntht) as
SELECT        P11.ARTID, (SUM(P11.PLDQTE)) AS plvqe, (SUM(P11.PLDMNTNETHT)) AS plvmntht
FROM         dbo.PIECEDIVERSLIGNES AS P11 FULL OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.PIECEDIVERS AS PV ON P11.PCDID = PV.PCDID
WHERE        (PV.PINCODE='STKOUT') AND (PV.DEPID_IN=1) AND (YEAR(PV.PCDDATEEFFET) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AND (MONTH(PV.PCDDATEEFFET) =6)
GROUP BY P11.ARTID
```

and this is the stock in view:

```
CREATE VIEW V_MOUVEMENT_02(ARTID,plvqe,plvmntht) as
SELECT        P11.ARTID, (SUM(P11.PLDQTE)) AS plvqe, (SUM(P11.PLDMNTNETHT)) AS plvmntht
  FROM  dbo.PIECEDIVERSLIGNES AS P11 FULL OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.PIECEDIVERS AS PV ON P11.PCDID = PV.PCDID
WHERE        (PV.PINCODE='STKIN') AND (PV.DEPID_IN=1) AND (YEAR(PV.PCDDATEEFFET) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AND (MONTH(PV.PCDDATEEFFET) =6)
GROUP BY P11.ARTID
```

and this one the final which keeps giving 14 lines:

```
select V1.ARTID , (V1.plvqe-V2.plvqe)FROM V_MOUVEMENT_01 AS V1 
INNER JOIN V_MOUVEMENT_02 AS V2 ON V1.ARTID=V2.ARTID
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help!

Comment: @AjayGupta  sorry i just add it now ...

Comment: @AzouzRh Provide us some sample data and as per your description use left outer join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the INNER JOIN.
Use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead.

```
SELECT V1.ARTID, V1.plvqe-ISNULL(V2.plvqe, 0) AS PLVQE
FROM V_MOUVEMENT_01 AS V1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN V_MOUVEMENT_02 AS V2 ON V1.ARTID = V2.ARTID
```

Comment: they use those articles for preparing biscuits . so sometimes some of those matters they need to bring them back to the stock .... that i why i did stock out minus stock out ... the problem that maybe they don't bring back all the matters .. so that's i still get problem and can't get thte 42 lines

Comment: u r a genius BRO thanks soooo much .... i don't know why i still have the join problems always but thank u anyways

Answer (score 0):

i used LEFT OUTER JOIN and it worked for me very well .... thanks @7schmiede